# C# - HTMLAgilityPack parsing keyword

Tags: c#, parsing, bots, html-agility-pack

I have a question about parsing with HTMLAgilityPack. As you see below, i have a code of a clothing webshop. Here are three diffrent pieces of clothing listed, with **(a class="name-link")** **the name** of the product with the **link to buy** the product. The other **(a class="name-link")** is the same product but then with the **color** of the product and the same product link as above.

So, the question now is: I want to get the productlink of the **"Cool Jacket"** in the color **"Black"**. I've already tought of first parsing the productname using my keyword variable with the string **"Cool Jacket"**, if it is, then find if there is a class that contains the string "Black". And then get then item link of the color black. But i can't figure out how to do that

**Also, the links of the three products have been randomly generated, so i can't parse the code and find for a link +**

**The name "Cool Jacket" and "Black" have been stored as a string in the variables "name" and "color"**

```html
<article>
  <div class="inner-article">
    <h1>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/7689">Cool Jacket</a>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/7689">Pink
    </p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="inner-article">
    <h1>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/5432">Cool jacket </a>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/5432">Black
    </p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="inner-article">
    <h1>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/2342">Really cool pants </a>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <a class="name-link" href="shop.com/2342">Green
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: it the HTML structure always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.. Please note that it will only work **if** there are only **2 anchor elements** under the main div element and the first one is the **Name** and the second is the **Color**.

1. First I wrote a simple class for the Item.

   ```
   public class Item
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Color { get; set; }
       public string Link { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Load the Html using HtmlAgilityPack

   ```
   var htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
   htmldoc.LoadHtml("<Your HTML>");
   ```
3. Fill the List through Parsing the HTML.

   ```
   var alldivElements = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='inner-article']");
   var itemList = new List<Item>();
       foreach (var div in alldivElements)
       {
           var anchorElements = div.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]");
           if(anchorElements.Count > 2) throw new Exception("Expected only 2 anchor elements");

           var item = new Item
           {
               Name =  anchorElements.ElementAt(0).InnerText.Trim(),
               Color = anchorElements.ElementAt(1).InnerText.Trim(),
               Link = anchorElements.ElementAt(0).Attributes["href"].Value.Trim()
           };
           itemList.Add(item);
       }
   ```
4. Since you've a list. Now you can easily query over the link using the name and the color.

   ```
   var color = "Black";
   var name = "Cool jacket";
   //To get the lick
   var link  = itemList.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Color == color && x.Name == name)?.Link; // will return null if item doesn't exist
   ```